# I'm recoloring my images with HTML5 canvas. How can I prevent IndexSizeError on reload in IE11?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, html, canvas

I have a Wordpress site and I'm trying to make some images in the loop being automatically recoloured. Sinceit has to work in IE 11, i'm recolouring them with HTML5 canvas, using:

```
<img id="desaturate-<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>" src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>">
<script>
    var imgObj = document.getElementById('desaturate-<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>'); 
    function gray(imgObj) {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        var canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');

        var imgW = imgObj.naturalWidth;
        var imgH = imgObj.naturalHeight;
        canvas.width = imgW;
        canvas.height = imgH;

        canvasContext.drawImage(imgObj, 0, 0);
        var imgPixels = canvasContext.getImageData(0, 0, imgW, imgH);

        for (var y = 0; y <imgPixels.height; y++) {
            for (var x = 0; x <imgPixels.width; x++) {
                var i = (y * 4) * imgPixels.width + x * 4;
                var avg = 0.34 * imgPixels.data[i] + 0.5 * imgPixels.data[i + 1] + 0.16 * imgPixels.data[i + 2];
                imgPixels.data[i] = avg;
                imgPixels.data[i + 1] = avg;
                imgPixels.data[i + 2] = avg;
             }
         }

         canvasContext.putImageData(imgPixels, 0, 0, 0, 0, imgPixels.width, imgPixels.height);
         return canvas.toDataURL();
    }
    imgObj.src = gray(imgObj);
</script>
```

At the first page load (type the URL, enter) everything works fine.
After I reload the page, IE11 Console shows IndexSizeError in this line:

```
var imgPixels = canvasContext.getImageData(0, 0, imgW, imgH);
```

In all other browsers I tested this with everythiong is OK, no matter reloaded or not.

What's wrong? Can I prevent IndexSizeError after reload?

Comment: have you checked imgW and imgH? are they 0? then the img is not ready yet, and you have to wait for the load-event

Comment: Yes, they were 0. Thanks a lot!